# Showing as much of a TiledMap as screen allows

Tags: libgdx

I have a simple 20 x 20 tile world (`TiledMap`) that I want to display using an `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer`. However, I'd like to show as much of the world as the screen will allow. This means if the screen is bigger, more of the world is shown and if the screen is smaller, less of the world is shown. **Is this even possible?**

The physical size of my tiles are 16 pixels x 16 pixels. So I thought that creating a 16 * 20 x 16 * 20 (320 x 320 unit?) `FillViewport` would do the trick, but that will always show the entire world on the screen (zooming in or out depending on screen size). Instead I want zoom to stay at 1 and cut off the world that is too wide or tall for the screen. How can I achieve this effect?

**Update**

I tried using a `ScreenViewport`, but it ends up looking like this: [image].

I've tried setting up my camera's position like so: `camera.position.set(viewport.getWorldWidth() / 2, viewport.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);` in my `create` method, but the camera's position is always 0, 0, 0.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/smoak/d2c1997199cf168c0a29) is the source code I am using so far.

Comment: `ScreenViewport` is the one you want.

Comment: When I try that, my screen looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/MeWjt0C.png I've tried doing `camera.position.set(viewport.getWorldWidth() / 2, viewport.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);` in my `create` method, but the camera's position is always 0, 0, 0.

Comment: Please show more code, we can only guess here.

Comment: Here is the source code: https://gist.github.com/smoak/d2c1997199cf168c0a29

Comment: Set the sizes of the viewport and camera. Update your camera after changing the position. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera And to get your desired effect, you need to move the camera while pinching out/in so that the edge stays at the left corner.